# Using a variable instead of a constant while formatting my output and need to left align it

Tags: c

This is a small portion of my code:

```
char *a;
asprintf(&a,"%%%ds",Max_FnLen);
printf(a,files[i-1]->d_name);
free(a); 
printf("%s",KNRM);
if ( (i % (180/Max_FnLen)) == 0) printf("\n");
```

Its running fine but I want to left align the output but it is coming right aligned by default can anyone help me with this.

Comment: To use a _variable_ to specfy the width, use e.g. `printf("%.*s", len, str)`. The `*` specifies a variable in the argument list is to be used for the width (or precission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "-" modifier like:
`printf("%-20s\n", "short line");`

In your case:

```
char *a;
asprintf(&a,"%%-%ds",Max_FnLen);
printf(a,files[i-1]->d_name);
free(a); 
printf("%s",KNRM);
if ( (i % (180/Max_FnLen)) == 0) printf("\n");
```

Comment: Thanks very much @MrCryo . It was a huge help!

Comment: `%-.*s` should be sufficient I think. (I might not remember the correct ordering, but you’ve got the idea)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-` flag, as described in the [ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/):

> -    Left-justify within the given field width; Right justification is the default (see width sub-specifier).

Comment: It works if we are using a constant value to fix the spaces but as I am using a variable it's not working